# Automatically assign a PDO type

Tags: php, pdo, bind

My PDO class has a function called bindParams, which has 2 parameters: setValues and setType,

Output result should be like:

```
$insertNews->bindParam(':news_title', $newsTitle, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

So, I am looking to automatically assign "PDO::PARAM_STR" to their values, which is in my case "news_title" is the variable setValues, and the "PDO::PARAM_STR" is the setType:

```
public final function bindParams($setValues=array(), $setType = null){

    //print_r($setValues);

    foreach ($setValues as $getVal) {

        echo $getVal.'<br />';

    if (is_null($setType)) {
        switch ($getVal) {
          case is_int($getVal):
              echo $getVal.' is INT<br />';
            $setType = PDO::PARAM_INT;
            break;
          case is_bool($getVal):
              echo $getVal.' is BOOL<br />';
            $setType = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
            break;
          case is_null($getVal):
              echo $getVal.' is NULL<br />';
            $setType = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
            break;
          default:
              echo $getVal.' is STR<br />';
            $setType = PDO::PARAM_STR;
        }
    } 


    }

} // end bindParams()

$con = new crud($dbCon);
$con->insert('ban_ip', array('visitor_type', 'ip'));
$con->bindParams(array('Visitor_Type', 1));
```

The output result is:

> Visitor_Type is STR

It is not looping the other value, which is 1.

EDIT: Correct code:

I think this one works:

```
public final function bindParams($setValues=array(), $setType = null){


    $combine = array_combine($this->insertedKeys, $setValues);

    foreach ($combine as $getKey => $getVal) {

        //echo 'key '.$getKey.' val '.$getVal.'<br />';

        switch ($getVal) {
        case is_int($getVal):
            echo $getVal .' is INT<br />';
            $setType = 'PDO::PARAM_INT';
            break;
        case is_bool($getVal):
            $setType = 'PDO::PARAM_BOOL';
            echo $getVal .' is BOOL<br />';
            break;
        case is_null($getVal):
            echo $getVal .' is NULL<br />';
            $setType = 'PDO::PARAM_NULL';
            break;
        default:
            echo $getVal .' is STR<br />';
            $setType = 'PDO::PARAM_STR';
            break;
    }


    echo "this->stmt->bindParams($getKey, $getVal, $setType)<br />";


    }


} // end bindParams()
```

The result is:

```
Visitor_Type is STR
this->stmt->bindParams(visitor_type, Visitor_Type, PDO::PARAM_STR)
1 is INT
this->stmt->bindParams(ip, 1, PDO::PARAM_INT)
```

And if I am not mistaken, I should only execute the code without any echo to run it.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is happening is, after you set $setType the first time through the loop, on subsequent iterations, is_null($setType) returns false, so the switch statement never evaluates.

There's a couple of different things you can do, depending upon whether you actually intend to pass in $setType. If you do not, then you should remove the $setType parameter and the is_null check, and then add your call to bindParam($getVal, $setType) after the switch statement.

Also, be careful with your switch statement value: you probably want to switch(true) (or just use if statements), not switch($getVal), because you will also get different results depending on the actual value (not just type) of $getVal.

Comment: Using `gettype` would be better for identifying the types and prevent any type ambiguity - http://php.net/gettype

Comment: Yeah, I am looking for 4 params ONLY: NULL, INT, STR or BOOL,.. I never used the rest in my bindParams